# Modify HTML Content Created by 3rd Party JS Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, okta

I am creating a custom sign in experience for a customer using okta Sign in Widget. As part of this 'widget' the function creates an HTML login form. One of the  tags this generates I want to modify the contents of after it has been generated on page load by the Okta widget.

I've created a fiddle where I used the following code to modify the contents but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var headingClass  = document.getElementsByClassName("okta-form-title");
headingClass.innerHTML = "<h2>Public Offers</h2>";
}) ;
```

Please could someone advise on how to get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` will give you an array of elements with that class name. So you need to iterate over it, or if you are sure there is only one element, use `getElementsByClassName[0]`

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var headingClass  = document.getElementsByClassName("okta-form-title");
    headingClass[0].innerHTML = "<h2>Public Offers</h2>";
}) ;
```

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName